# Java FX 8 - Tableview Display Objects Within Objects

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to load a **Tableview** component from a list of Objects, in my case client objects. A client object contains an **Address** Object and Vice Versa.
The **Client** and Address object are defined as follows;

```
public class Client{

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String emailAddress;
   private String phoneNumber;

   private Address clientsAddress;

   public Client(){
     //blah blah
   }

   //getters
   ...
   //setters
   ...
}

public class Address{

   //address lines + county
   private String a1;
   private String a2;
   private String a3;
   private String county;

   private Client client;

   public Address(){
     //blah blah
   }

   //getters
   ...
   //setters
   ...
}
```

I can get the Client's fields to appear in the table view mapping the field name inside the client Object to the Column.

```
final TableView<Client> tableView = new TableView<>();
final TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
final TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
final TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email Address");
final TableColumn addressCol1 = new TableColumn("Address Line 1");
final TableColumn addressCol2 = new TableColumn("Address Line 2");

firstNameCol.setMinWidth(90);
firstNameCol.setMaxWidth(110);
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

lastNameCol.setMinWidth(90);
lastNameCol.setMaxWidth(110);
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

emailCol.setMinWidth(100);
emailCol.setMaxWidth(210);
emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("emailAddress"));

//Don't know how to access the Address Object inside Client Object in Next two parts

addressColumn1.setMinWidth(100);
addressColumn1.setMaxWidth(200);
addressColumn1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(""));

adddessColumn2.setMinWidth(100);
addressColumn2.setMaxWidth(200);
addressColumn2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(""));

tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, addressColumn1, addressColumn2);
```

My problem is however, is there any way of accessing the address object inside the client object, or any way of mapping the field name in the Address object to the table column. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: afaik, there's no in-built support for binding paths- you have to implement a custom valueFactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, I got it working by overriding the **call** method which is able to access the client object. Then I was able to access the Address Object and return a **SimpleStringProperty** and update each column appropriately.

```
addressColumn1.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Client, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Client, String> c) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getAddress().getA1());                
        }
});
```