# JavaFX 8 - Bind TableView Selection Model Property

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to bind the selected row of a TableView to an object?

I have a TableView that is bound to an ObservableList of song objects.  I also have a song object of the currently playing song.  What I want is for when the currently playing song object changes, the selected row of the table view will change to that song.

Here is the current song object.

```
private ObjectProperty<JSong> currentSong;

@FXML
private TableView<JSong> songsTable;
```

I see I can bind to the table's selection model property but I can't figure out how to pass the song object to it.

`songsTable.selectionModelProperty().bind(???)`

Comment: This is possible, I have written about it here: http://eckig.github.io/blog/2014/12/05/bidirectional-binding-for-selection-model/

Comment: This may also help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020647/java-fx-8-tableview-display-objects-within-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Listener to the currentSong property.

```
ObjectProperty<JSong> currentSong;
TableView<JSong> songsTable;
currentSong.addListener(new ChangeListener<JSong>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends JSong> observable,
                JSong oldValue, JSong newValue) {
            songsTable.getSelectionModel().select(newValue);

        }
    });
```

Comment: how to bind tableView row with currentSong?